# katalon studio can't load my variables at variable binding section

Tags: automated-tests, katalon-studio

I wrote a test case and save all text field as variables 
then I filled in the values in excel, but after I add my Test case and test data to test suite,the variable section can't load my variables.
How does this comes out ?

1.Test suite screenshot
[image]

2.Variables in test case
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be the case that your variables are not setup properly in Variables section of your Test Case.

[image: Add Variables to Test Cases]

Comment: Yes yes, that 's the answer I was looking for ,thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

After you created your data file you have to use getter to use up values in a test case. A short example:

```
TestData accounts = findTestData('Data Files/Your data file');
int rows = accounts.getRowNumbers()
for (i in 1..rows) {
    println accounts.getObjectValue('username', i)
}
```

Comment: I have add my variables and findTestDate in front ,but the binding section still not able to map my variables.

Comment: You can use a single variable like this:
`WebUI.setText(findTestObject('input_field_for_username'), findTestData 'Properties_datafile').getValue('userName', 1))`

Comment: I see ,I can call variable value directly from script but I just want to know why I can't see to mapping like all the tutorial video .

Comment: If it uses up your variable values, it is working correctly.